# WebStorm: Is it possible to have the terminal run vertically?

Tags: terminal, ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have recently started using WebStorm. The embedded terminal is great but I would really like to have it run vertically on the right side instead of running horizontally across the bottom of the editor.

Is it possible to have the terminal run vertically?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. When the terminal is open, on the top right there is a settings button.

In settings ==> Move to ==> right